# Visual studio 2010 rebuilds with no modifications?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I found something strange when i was building a project, after I built my project, I can get the latest output file (.exe) and then I tried building the project again.

As far as I know, at this time visual studio won't make a new output file again, but it made a newer file again even though I didn't modify any source codes.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4):

> as i know, at this time visual studio must not make a new output file again.

Visual Studio rebuilds the file even if there are no code changes.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio does not recompile if there no changes, but always generates (build) a new executable.